# Kafka Offset after retention period

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a kafka topic with 1 partition. if it had 100 messages in it the offset would be from 0.99.

According the kafka retention policy all of the messages will be wiped out after the specified period.

and i am sending 100 new messages to the topic once all have been wiped out(after retention period). Now, where would the new offset of the message start from? is it From 100 or from 0??

I am trying to understand whether the new offsets will be 100-199 or 0-99?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kafka honors the log retention policy by deleting log segments which satisfy the predicate and it will not never remove the active log segment which means the base offset of the active log segment will always be kept.

As for your example, if the first batch of 100 messages are all in a same log segment, Kafka will create a new log segment with the base offset of 100 and delete the old segment after a log-retention-period amount of time passed. So a new message starts offset at 100.

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful.